# FileNotFoundException in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to convert the image to a byte array to upload it on SQL database, the project builds successfully but on database updating using the code-first approach in entity framework, i am getting the file not found exception, but the file is there in app_data.

```
public override void Up()
    {

        Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Movies ON");
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"c:\users\erprakash\source\DeltaXIMDB\DeltaXIMDB\App_Data\om.png");
        byte[] byteimage = imageToByteArray(image); 
        Sql($"INSERT INTO Movies(Id,Name,YearOfRelease,Plot,Image) VALUES(1,'Mission Impossible Fallout','2018',{byteimage}");
        Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Movies OFF");
    }
```

If any suggestion and solution, please share.
Thank you

Comment: Just a note: the image is already binary on disk, why load it as an Image and convert to binary? Just load the file? As for the error, are permissions set properly?

Comment: about your sql: note that with the usual seed value, the IDENTITY_INSERT does not fulfill any purpose. Also note that the value you are trying to insert is lacking the Plot parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For MVC3 and below:

```
string file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/om.png");
```

For MVC4 > :

```
string file = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/om.png");
```

from your code you can use it:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(file);
```